# Selenium check if element exists without exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-rc

I want to just check if an element is there or not within a for loop but it just throws an exception and ends the code. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `driver.find_element` you should use `driver.find_elements` method here.
Something like this:

```py
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/div[@class='class_name']"):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/div[@class='class_name']").click()
```

Or this:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/div[@class='class_name']")
if elements:
    elements[0].click()
```

`driver.find_elements` will return you a **list** of web elements matching the passed locator. In case such elements found it will return non-empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `True` while if no matches found it will give you an empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `False`

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, but I'm using it in a for loop. How would you go about writing an if else/elif for the element not existing? like a boolean kind of answer. It keeps saying the wrong one

Comment: My answer includes what you asking for. What do you want to do in case the element existing and what in other case?

Comment: I just want a simple yes or no, but it keeps telling me either yes all the time or no all the time, like its not really checking anything. How do I like store it as a boolean value in a way or something like that?

Comment: try:
        check = web.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "zip_code_address unused-hide")
        print ("Yes")

    except:
        print ("Not")

Comment: This keeps evaluating to not for some reason

Comment: when there's a space in the style it means there are two style classes associated with the element.  Change your locator accordingly... for instance you might use XPATH and contains[@class, "zip_code_address"]... or with CLASS_NAME it might match "zip_code_address" or "unused-hide".

Comment: @HocianWade Sorry, I was busy. Did pcalkins answer your question?

Comment: Yea i got it figured out

Comment: Great! You are welcome!

Comment: oh, so findelement gives you either an exception error if it doesnt find any or the element, but findelements give you a empty list or a list which you can use as boolean value. Interesting